# How to fix this issue with git push?

Tags: flutter, git, github, push, git-bash

I faced this issue via trying to push my local repository to my GitHub account.

Then I got this error message.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/example.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21151 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I tried it several times.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably having connectivity issues with [https://github.com/](https://github.com) are you able to open it in your web browser?

Comment: Yes. My issue was the proxy settings of my public Wi-Fi network does not allowed to upload dome flutter files.

Answer (score -1):

This can be happened due to your proxy settings. I changed my network to my mobile network from our university Wi-Fi network. Then it worked!
In here the issue was some files couldn't be uploaded via our university Wi-Fi network due to their proxy settings.